# How do I save state of a toggle button in a Data Grid in C# - WPF?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I changed the toggle button State into "ON" mode and close the application. But when I run the program again that toggle button resets into "OFF" mode. How can I save the toggle button state when I switched into "ON" or "OFF" mode? [(According to the attached Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZiwG.jpg)

Comment: Create a TwoWay binding to the underlying persisted object and persist it.

Comment: @Firo I will try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I was creating a trial effect toggle for my unity game. I solved the problem with storing the toggle on or off information in a PlayerPref. Maybe this could help you:

```
public Toggle myToggle;
    void Start() {
        bool isToggleOn = (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isToggleOn") == 1) ? true : false;
        myToggle.isOn = isToggleOn;
    }
```

I don't know the exact answer for your solution but you can use the same storing way and it probably will work. This is the toggle function when I click the toggle and change the PlayerPref according to that function:

```
public void SetTrailEffect (bool isToggle) {
        if(isToggle){
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isToggleOn", 1);   
        } else {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isToggleOn", 0);
        }
    }
```